# Can Google Chrome Frame be installed on a Windows Terminal Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, terminal-server, google-chrome

Thinking about installing it on our Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server, but I cannot find any documentation if it work correctly in that environment. I'd want it to be the default renderer for all of our users within IE8. Thanks!

Comment: Anyword on this?

Comment: Actually, I revisited this about 2 weeks ago.  I'll post what I can find.